# in drupal the view created is not fetching all the details of the single person in row

Tags: drupal, view

I have created a view to fetch the details of members registered to my site through views data source module,but the details of the same person are taking 3-4 lines in the table format,and skipping to other line,Please give me the solution

Thanks
veena

Comment: give us little more picture what you have done

Comment: Actually the steps for registration are in 4 division,so the data from each step is taking single different lines in excel,so how to aggregate and fetch all the details in single line in excel reports?